# Javascript Url manipulation and back navigation

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate

I am updating the url with something like this:

```
window.history.pushState(null, "Page title", "/?param=" + myParamValue);
```

This works fine, but when the user hits the back button, the url gets updated but the page does not reload.

I have an ajax routine that updates the content but if possible I don't want to mess with re-implementing back/forward navigation, and I just want the page to reload in case of the user hitting back/forward browser buttons.

**Q**: Is there a way to force the page to reload the given url on browser back/forward actions from the user?

**Bonus Q**: also, what if the browser doesn't support `window.history.pushState` on older browsers? Shall I surround that code in a try/catch block?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571734/html5-history-api-demo

Answer (score 3):

```
if(typeof window.history.pushState === 'function')
    //handle your url rewriting
else
    //support for older browsers
```

As for your question about back-button support, the link provided in the comment provides very nice implementations for the feature

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this jQuery plugin, it might be useful for you:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

I found it reading this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin

I hope it helps.

About the old browser question, I don't think you have to bother with that because you are using ajax, which requires a modern browser too. The main question is: who will visit your web site? If it's mainly people over 40yo, maybe you should bother...

Just my opinion ;)

**Edit: Be careful with IE9, it's not handled in it. thx to nbrooks for the info**

Comment: Thanks, about the cross-browser support... LOL - someone could be on IE8/9 or smt, but yeah not a big concern :)

Comment: IE 9 handle this !!  Doesn't it?? IE8 is another story... :) And as i said:just my opinion. I don't bother with old browser anymore, I just check with PHP and echo a: "go get a real browser" page. It may be dumb, but it's a choice to make.

Comment: @Maresh nah it's not supported til IE 10

Comment: wow... It's a shame, IE9 has a good JS engine, and some other stuff i like, It's going back down in my esteem...