# change url with jquery like facebook messages

Tags: jquery, facebook, url

May be you think this is Duplicated, But This is not duplicated.

[change-hash-without-reload-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939041/change-hash-without-reload-in-jquery)
in this topic you change url after a `#` character but if you take a look at facebook message url change, you can see that facebook change url without any extra `#` character.

```
facebook.com/message/user1
```

and if you click on second user message it will be change like:

```
facebook.com/message/user2
```

This url change without redirecting and using a # character.

Comment: This is most likely server side URL Rewriting.

Comment: It's called the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), and this is a duplicate of a bunch of similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) is your best bet for accomplishing this with cross browser support. You should realize that older browsers do not support direct manipulation of the URL and the hash tag (#) mechanism is used in its place.

Here is a portion of their getting started section:

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    });

    // Change our States
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"); // logs {state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"
    History.replaceState({state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4"); // logs {}, '', "?state=4"
    History.back(); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.back(); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.back(); // logs {}, "Home Page", "?"
    History.go(2); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"

})(window);
```

Check out these examples using [HTML5 pustState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) directly:

- http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/CukUH/show
- http://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/show/

Questions of a similar topic:

- [HTML5 History API Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571734/html5-history-api-demo)
- [Good tutorial for using HTML5 History API (Pushstate?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate)

Other Resources:

- http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2011/2/2/degradable-javascript-applications-using-html5-pushstate
- http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate